# Basic statistical equation

Tags: variance, econometrics

How would I go about showing that:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^2=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2-n\bar{X}^2\,,$$ (where $\bar{X}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Since this is a routine book-work question, it should carry the `self-study` tag  - and whose [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) you should read and follow the guidelines of (i.e. edit your question). Specifically, what have you tried and what problems did you have?

Comment: As for a big hint: expand the quadratic. Separate out the terms into their own sums. Simplify the terms and cancel where appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much. It took a little bit of research into the properties of the summation operator but once I understood these I figured out how to show this using the steps you provided.

Comment: Would you like to write up an answer? If you write it I'm happy to clean up the formatting. You might as well have the reputation.

Comment: Done - really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

The first step is to expand the quadratic, the second is to express each term with its own sum, the third is to simplify and the fourth is to cancel out.

\begin{eqnarray}
\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar X)^2 &=& \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i^2-2X_i\bar X+\bar X^2)\\
 &=& \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2-2\bar X\sum_{i=1}^n X_i+n(\bar X^2)\\
 &=& \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2-2n(\bar X^2)+n(\bar X^2)\\
 &=& \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2-n(\bar X^2)
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: For theses type of questions (i.e. self-study tags), you need to provide some hints, not the full answer. Try not to solve their assignments!

Comment: @Stat The OP is answering his own question (on the basis of some suggestions about how to approach it) - and providing a full answer at my invitation. People solving their own problems is perfectly okay on self-study questions.

Comment: LOL, I didn't check that out!

Comment: (+1) Alternatively, a geometric interpretation makes short work of this result, which asserts the Pythagorean Theorem holds for a triangle with hypotenuse $x=(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ and leg $y=(\bar{X},\bar{X},\ldots,\bar{X})$. To verify this you only need check that the two legs are perpendicular; that is, $(x-y)\cdot y=0$; equivalently, that $x\cdot y=y\cdot y.$  But since $\sum_i X_i=\sum_i \bar{X},$ both dot products equal $\bar{X}\sum_i X_i$, QED.